# Ubuntu 17.10.1 overheating on laptop with GTX 1060 Mobile and i7 7700hq CPU

Tags: intel-graphics, overheating, nvidia-prime, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

My laptop is overheating on new ubuntu installation. I have tried propriety nvidia 
drivers and set `select-prime` to `intel` and `nvidia` both vise versa, but the problem persists on both selected GPU. No matter what gpu is selected `sensors` showing skylake(intel) gpu is on and overheatin. How can i fix this?

Comment: okk so i mistook the the pch_skylake-virtual-0 as intel skylake GPU, and 75 degrees are normal for pch chips, same is on windows. so it's pretty normal i guess.

Answer (score 1):

okk so i mistook the the pch_skylake-virtual-0 as intel skylake GPU, and 75 degrees are normal for pch chips, same is on windows. so it's pretty normal i guess, it concludes that my laptop is running normal. because CPU core temps never exceeded 55 degree Celsius.